# PHP 7 class not working, it returns blank page

Tags: php, php-7

Good morning.
I'm completing an exercise from     Doug Bierer book and the result of the deep web scanner is a blank page. The autoload is working. I can't find the issue. Can some one help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

Chap_01_deep_scan_website.php:

```
<?php

   require __DIR__ . '/Application/Autoload/Loader.php';
   Application\Autoload\Loader::init(__DIR__ . '');
   $deep = new Application\Web\Deep();

   define('DEFAULT_URL', 'oreilly.com');
   define('DEFAULT_TAG', 'img');
   $url = strip_tags($_GET['url'] ?? DEFAULT_URL);
   $tag = strip_tags($_GET['tag'] ?? DEFAULT_TAG);
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    <title>Deep Web Scan</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
  foreach ($deep->scan($url, $tag) as $item) {
    $src = $item['attributes']['src'] ?? NULL;
    if($src && (stripos($src, 'png') || stripos($src, 'jpg'))) {
        printf('<br>1<img src="%s"/>', $src);
    }
  }
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Deep.php:

```
 namespace Application\Web;

 class Deep {
    protected $domain;

    public function getDomain($url) {
        if(!$this->domain) {
            $this->domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        }
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function scan($url, $tag) {

        $vac = new Hoover();
        $scan = $vac->getAttribute($url, 'href',$this->getDomain($url));
        $result = array();
        foreach($scan as $subSite) {
            yield from $vac->getTags($subSite, $tag);
        }
        return count($scan);
    }
 }
```

Comment: _"is a blank page"_ - does the included html get rendered (do you see the right title)? Do you have error_reporting switched on?

Comment: Yes <title>Deep Web Scan</title>.

Comment: Thank you, in the book says, Go ahead and define the Application\Web\Deep class, as well as the Application\Web\Hoover class in the previous recipe (That one worked). Here is the repo https://github.com/PacktPublishing/PHP-7-Programming-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter%2001/source/chapter01/chap_01_deep_scan_website.php, I tried to run the code from the repo and still get a blank page. So it seems that the code from the book is broken as well.

Comment: Turned on error reporting. No errors reported.

Comment: Does `$deep->scan()` actually yield any results? Does `$item` contain `attributes` and `src`? Does that source contain `png` or `jpg`? If any of those questions are answered with "no", then your code will not render anything within the `<body>` tag.